# Shell Script to find PID of ssh and kill the PID if present

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to write a script to find a reverse SSH PID and kill it if present. I am stuck on "awk" as it gives error. below is the script:

```
a=('ps -aef | grep "ssh -fN" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'')

if [ -n "$a" ]

then

    echo "String \"$a\" is not null."
    kill -9 "$a" 

fi
```

I commented out if, then, kill and fi lines to debug the script. I get following error:

```
String "ps -aef | grep "ssh -fN" | grep -v grep | awk {" is not null.
```

I believe parenthesis for awk is creating the problem and I am unable to get a workaround for this. On Command line, this works perfectly and returns the correct PID.

```
ps -aef | grep "ssh -fN" | grep -v grep | (awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Once the PID is passed on to variable "a", I need to issue kill command. OS is Centos 6.4

P.S: I am not fluent on scripting but trying to achieve an objective. Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your script.

- You need command substitution to store the output of `ps` pipeline into an array.
- You need to check for the number of elements in the array.
- Refer to the *array* instead of the *variable*.

The following might work for you:

```
pids=( $(ps -ef | grep '[s]sh -fN' | awk '{print $2}') )
if [ "${#pids[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
  kill -9 "${pids[@]}";
fi
```

Comment: I tried as it is. Got following:    kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

Comment: @user3132483 Your comment didn't indicate what you got.  However, I realized that there was a typo in the `kill -9` line.  Check the update above.

Comment: changing foo to pids made the difference. I think it worked. Will confirm in a short while.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have `grep` and then `awk`, you can get rid of the greps:

```
ps -aef | grep "ssh -fN" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'

ps -aef |awk  ' { if ( ($0 ~ /ssh -FN/) &&  (! $0 ~ /grep/) ) { print $2 } }'
```

However, instead of using `ps`, use [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep).

```
pgrep -f "ssh -[fN][fN]"  # Will match against either 'ssh -fN' or 'ssh -Nf'
```

There is even a [`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) that will do the entire command for you:

```
pkill -f "ssh -[fN][fN]"
```

That will find all of the processes that match that particular string and kill them (if they exist).